# Is the old man cleaning in Nirvana's Smells Like Teen Spirit music video supposed to mean something?

Tags: meaning, music-video

In the [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTWKbfoikeg) from [Nirvana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_(band))'s *Smells Like Teen Spirit*, there is a scene that's repeated again and again of an old man with (what I believe is) a cleaning broom doing some strange move repeatedly. Is this supposed to mean something? Why do they show this several times across the video?